# What is the expected behaviour of a write after fchmod?

Tags: c, file, posix, file-permissions

If I open and create a file for r/w access then subsequently use fchmod to remove write access what is the expected behaviour of a write on the same file descriptor directly after the fchmod call and before closing/reopening that file?

Is this specified by POSIX?

Are permissions only checked on an open?

Comment: It seems to me you could find out by writing a three line program.

Comment: I know what it *does* (I don't see a failed write, which I did not expect). I want to know what is the specified behaviour and why.

Comment: From the accepted answer in this thread http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89045/file-permissions-and-saving it seems that file permissions are only checked when the file is opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a fully-conforming implementation, it appears that changing the permissions of the file after it has been opened should have no effect on already-open file descriptors.

From the version 7 [`chmod()`/`fchmodat()` documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/chmod.html):

> **APPLICATION USAGE**
>
> ...
>
> Any file descriptors currently open by any process on the file could
>   possibly become invalid if the mode of the file is changed to a value
>   which would deny access to that process. One situation where this
>   could occur is on a stateless file system. **This behavior will not
>   occur in a conforming environment**.

This differs from the version 6 of POSIX, where [the `chmod()` documentation states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chmod.html):

> The effect on file descriptors for files open at the time of a call to
>   chmod() is implementation-defined.

Comment: I read that as "this behavior" refers to the "become invalid" part. Ie. calling `chmod` cannot invalidate opened file descriptors - that doesn't mean it can't change the permissions though. Take NFS eg., where changing the permissions will immediately influence already opened files (because it happens server side).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I read it the same way.  Since the question is *what is the expected behaviour of a write on the same file descriptor directly after the `fchmod` call*, this not-very-clear statement in the standard indicates that the already-open descriptor should still be valid.  If a file is opened for writing and the permissions changed afterwards to remove write permissions from the file, the still-open descriptor should not be invalidated.

Comment: The point I tried to make (apparently badly) is that the guarantee that it won't invalidate open file descriptors does not mean it has "no effect on already-open file descriptors". Or specifically wrt this question, I haven't found it stated that a permission error results in an invalid file descriptor. But maybe I'm overlooking something ?

Comment: Or to make it more explicit, the `EACCES` error (permission issue) is distinct from the `EBADF` error (invalid file descriptor). Both can be returned by [`write`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I see what you mean. The standard's use of "invalid" isn't exactly clear. I'd think a file descriptor opened for writing but that the process can no longer write to would be "invalid", but I don't see that clearly stated in the standard. I can only say that the standard uses the words "deny access", which to me at least implies an `EACCESS` error - and the standard later says "This behavior will not occur".

Comment: On a stateless file system (which is the example they use), an `EACCESS` error can indeed lead to an `EBADF` error, because there's no way to know how or when the file was opened (no state is kept). All that's known after revoking write privileges with `chmod`, is that the file couldn't have been opened for writing, so any `write` call for that file could be interpreted as an invalid request (depending on the implementation). However, on stateful file systems (like most mainstream file systems) that problem doesn't present itself, since state is kept about how the file was opened.

Comment: Bottom line : they could have been a bit clearer in their choice of words heh. Fortunately, most operating systems implement permission checks on `open` only. With some file systems (NFS eg.) that gets a bit tricky though.

Answer (score 1):

From the reference page on [`chmod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/chmod.html) (which has the same behavior as [`fchmod`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fchmod.html)) :

> The effect on file descriptors for files open at the time of a call to `chmod()` is implementation-defined.

So, this is not defined by POSIX, and you'll have to consult your platform documentation.

Comment: That's not the latest version of the POSIX specification.

Comment: @AndrewHenle : true, but I don't see a real difference with the latest version (which only just became the current version this year).

Comment: @AndrewHenle : in fact - the same quote from your answer was already present in issue 6.

Comment: That would seem to make issue 6 inconsistent then, wouldn't it?  "Implemenation-defined" in one place and "become invalid ... will not occur in a conforming environment" in another.

Comment: @AndrewHenle : that's where we read it differently I guess (ref. my comments to your answer - this is a weird conversation lol).